# Aerospike Timeout Exception

Tags: timeout, cluster-computing, key-value-store, aerospike

I have an application that users a lot of batch reads in Aerospike. After some time the application is running, I get a lot these errors:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[AerospikeException: Error Code 9: Timeout]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:316) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:46) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error Code 9: Timeout
    at com.aerospike.client.command.MultiCommand.parseGroup(MultiCommand.java:96) ~[com.aerospike.aerospike-client-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.aerospike.client.command.MultiCommand.parseResult(MultiCommand.java:71) ~[com.aerospike.aerospike-client-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.aerospike.client.command.SyncCommand.execute(SyncCommand.java:57) ~[com.aerospike.aerospike-client-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at com.aerospike.client.command.Executor$ExecutorThread.run(Executor.java:127) ~[com.aerospike.aerospike-client-3.2.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
```

I think it is something related to batch reads, because the batch_index_timeout gets incremented on every timeout exception. My database has a lot of large records (512K-1M) that are retrieved in these batch get operations.

I have a 5 nodes cluster, all of them are 2 CPUs, 3.5GB RAM each. Bellow there is a graph of the moment when the reads per second drops, which is exactly when the error starts happening. Is this a problem in the client or in the server? Both seems to be running ok with low cpu, network and memory consumption.

[image]

**Edit 1**:
After some tests, I noticed that when the servers have more memory available operates at a lower level of I/O. I think this is because operational system disk cache is working and avoiding disk operations at common accessed areas. This can clearly be seen in the graph bellow:

[image]

- I have 1 node with SSD, 3.5G RAM and storage configured to device
  /dev/sdb
- I have 5 nodes with HDD, 7.5G RAM and storage configured to file /data/aerospike.dat

In the beginning, the HDD nodes increase I/O, but after some time it goes down and operated normally. The SDD server, with few memory, is always reading from disk. When I increase load in the cluster, this has a lot of impact on the SDD, but low impact on the HDD servers. With this configuration, there is no more timeout events.

**Edit 2:**

I started I completely new test environment, with 3 aerospike servers: 6CPU, 21GB RAM, 200GB SSD each. Replication factor of 2. This configuration can handle a lot more requests than the configuration before (40000 TPS at the moment). But even this config gets to a point where I get a lot of timeouts. The odd thing is that only one of the two servers present timeout errors in the monitoring (err_tsvc_requests_timeout variable). The other difference is that batch_index_timeout is not happening anymore, only err_tsvc_requests_timeout, and only in one of the three servers. Bellow the graphs of the 3 servers. The one with timeout problem is aerospike-new2. The aerospike-new3 was added after some time the other two were already running.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) What is the timeout set to for batch operations?

2) How many records are you fetching at a time?

3) Are you using persistence, if so what type?

Comment: Can you output from `iostat`? You may be exceeding the read throughput of your disks. Last we talked about it, you were storing data on HDD storage.

Comment: One of the servers has SSD and it is the only server that does not increase the number of batch_index_timeout. Maybe you are right, but when looking at google monitoring, Disk I/O is 70% of its capacity in all servers

Comment: If it is I/O capacity problem, why does the problem takes almost 10 minutes to appear?

Comment: Definitely check SSD versus NVMe SSD on GCE. There's a measurable performance difference between them. Also, the timeout problem is related to latency, not throughput. You might be able to pump out more data, but the disk just can't reach all the records in the batch fast enough. The NVMe SSDs will have the best latency characteristics.

Comment: There has been a lot of work done by GCE regarding SSD performance. It would be worth rechecking the behavior with new instances (launched after September 2016) and the latest Aerospike version.

Comment: I followed @RonenBotzer recommendation and at a first glance everything looked amazing. The cluster with 5 servers was running with very low CPU usage (only 20% comparing to 75% of the old servers). I decided to remove 1 server and operate with 4 servers. Then the cluster got crazy! I put the removed server back, but it is still crazy. I added another 6th server, and things did not get any better. It still shows [Timeout: Client timeout: timeout=5000 iterations=1 failedNodes=0 failedConns=0 lastNode=BB91F00F00A0142 10.240.0.31:3000]] - it oscillates between normal and odd behavior

Comment: Reg why it takes 10 mins for the problem to appear : GCE (or any cloud provider for that matter), will let you burst for some time beyond the average limit. This is to allow occasional bursts. If they burst continues, they will then clamp down to the permissible limit.