# Aerospike error: All batch queues are full

Tags: google-cloud-platform, aerospike

I am running an Aerospike cluster in Google Cloud. Following the recommendation on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155181/aerospike-timeout-exception), I updated to the last version (3.11.1.1) and re-created all servers. In fact, this change cause my 5 servers to operate in a much lower CPU load (it was around 75% load before, now it is on 20%, as show in the graph bellow:

[image]

Because of this low load, I decided to reduce the cluster size to 4 servers. When I did this, my application started to receive the following error:

**`All batch queues are full`**

I found this [discussion about the topic](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/error-message-all-batch-queues-are-full/1856/3), recommending to change the parameters `batch-index-threads` and `batch-max-unused-buffers` with the command

`asadm -e "asinfo -v 'set-config:context=service;batch-index-threads=NEW_VALUE'"`

I tried many combinations of values (batch-index-threads with 2,4,8,16) and none of them solved the problem, and also changing the `batch-index-threads` param. Nothing solves my problem. I keep receiving the **`All batch queues are full`** error.

Here is my aerospace.conf relevant information:

```
service {
    user root
    group root
    paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
        paxos-recovery-policy auto-reset-master
    pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
    service-threads 32
    transaction-queues 32
    transaction-threads-per-queue 4
    batch-index-threads 40
    proto-fd-max 15000
    batch-max-requests 30000
    replication-fire-and-forget true
}
```

I use 300GB SSD disks on these servers.

Comment: I have a suspicion that you are hitting the disk IOPS limit. If you hit the limit, the batch operation will spend time at disk IO. This will reduce the CPU utilization also as aerospike cannot perform lot of work. Can you enable details batch benchmarks by doing : asadm -e "asinfo -v 'set-config:context=namespace;id=test;enable-benchmarks-batch-sub=true'". It will give details about where the batch call is spending most of its time.

Answer (score 2):

A quick note which may or may not pertain to you:

> A common mistake we have seen in the past is that developers decide to use 'batch get' as a general purpose 'get' for single and multiple record requests. The single record get will perform better for single record requests.

It's possible that you are being constrained by the network between the clients and servers. Reducing from 5 to 4 nodes reduced the aggregate pipe. In addition, removing a node will start cluster migrations which adds additional network load.

Comment: My clients are 1CPU servers, which limits them to 2Gbps. From the network monitoring graph, these servers are operating at 150MBs (1.2Gbps), which is far from the upper limit. My servers are bounded to 8Gbps, and are operating at 600MBs (4.8Gps) also far bellow the cap.  (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#egress_throughput_caps)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the [`batch-max-buffer-per-queue`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/batch.html#batch-index) config parameter.

> Maximum number of 128KB response buffers allowed in each batch index
>   queue. If all batch index queues are full, new batch requests are
>   rejected.

In conjunction with raising this value from the default of 255 you will want to also raise the `batch-max-unused-buffers` to `batch-index-threads` x `batch-max-buffer-per-queue` + 1 (at least). If you do not do that new buffers will be created and destroyed constantly, as the amount of free (unused) buffers is smaller than the ones you're using. The moment the batch response is served the system will strive to trim the buffers down to the max unused number. You will see this reflected in the `batch_index_created_buffers` metric constantly rising.

Be aware that you need to have enough DRAM for this. For example if you raise the `batch-max-buffer-per-queue` to 320 you will consume

```
40 (`batch-index-threads`) x 320 (`batch-max-buffer-per-queue`) x 128K = 1600MB
```

For the sake of performance the `batch-max-unused-buffers` should be set to 13000 which will have a max memory consumption of 1625MB (1.59GB) per-node.

Comment: I did changed the `batch-max-unused-buffers` to 21000 (40 * 512) + some buffer, but the problem persists. I still see the same errors and the `batch_index_created_buffers` is constantly rising

Comment: It's a sign that there aren't enough unused buffers around, but I am weirded out by why it's larger than your `batch-index-threads` x `batch-max-bugger-per-queue`... Can you double check the param settings?

Comment: By the way, this knowledge base article goes over this topic: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/batch-full-error/4329